# How to get complete stored history in IPython?

Tags: ipython

And I mean *get* it. Not *print* it.

All the other answers to similiar questions are about printing.

I know can open and the sqlite but is there a direct way from 'import IPython' that is future proof?

One way might be:

```py
i = IPython.get_ipython()
list(i.history_manager.db.execute('select * from history'))
```

Comment: ist(i.history_manager.db.execute('select * from history'))